# I'm making a tic tac toe game but it just puts X

Tags: c#, webforms, tic-tac-toe

[image]
I'm doing a tic tac toe game but it just puts X. I do it on the web form without using the master page

```
 bool turn = true;
        int turn_count = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void bclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            if (turn)
            {
                b.Text = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                b.Text = "O";
            }
            turn = !turn;
            b.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your page is posting back when you submit. It creates a new page instance and `turn` will always be `true` because it is a new instance (a Page is a class). You need to store `turn` across postback, like in a Session variable. And also, webforms is dead.

Comment: I understand thank you. This is my homework. I have to use web form. @Crowcoder

Comment: Yes, I understand too. WebForms is commonly taught and it is a tremendous disservice to students.

Comment: BTW, I have written a tic tac toe engine, in case you find it of any use. It was built for a presentation and is not exactly polished, but [here it is](https://github.com/crowcoder/PostmanDelivers/tree/master/TikTakToe.Engine)

Comment: I still haven't found how to fix the problem. Is there anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Store `turn` in Session. Note you will also have the same problem with `turn_count`. I don't really understand where you were going with the boolean. If you are expecting two different players on two browsers to play this game then you need a lot more work to track game state and what players are active in what game instance.

```
protected void bclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string whosTurn = "X";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["turn"] as string))
    {
        whosTurn = Session["turn"].ToString();
    }

    if(whosTurn == "X")
    {
        Session["turn"] = "O";
    }
    else
    {
        Session["turn"] = "X";
    }

    Button b = (Button)sender;
    
    b.Text = whosTurn;

    b.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I understood how to solve

Comment: If you have implemented my code you are probably getting an exception because `turn` is not a boolean in my example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that your page is posting back and its initialising turn to true every time.
you should use sessions for this. e.g. inside Page_Load Method Use:

```
Session["Turn"] = true;
```

and inside button set it to true or false accordingly.